# Shorter proof for this?

Tags: problem-solving

if $G = T + N$ and $T = N * t$, where $t$ is a $\%$, find $T$ if the only given values are $G$ and $t$.

I already has a formula but it needs to compute for $N$ first which is lengthy, is there a shorter formula without computing for $N$ first?

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$G=N\cdot t+N=N\cdot(1+t)$$
$$N=\frac{G}{1+t}$$
$$T=\frac{G\cdot t}{1+t}$$

Comment: Compact and short nice answer. ;)